# What's the difference between get_home_path() and ABSPATH?

Tags: core, paths

What's the difference between `get_home_path()` and `ABSPATH`? 
Isn't the point of both to point to the WordPress install root?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

They ***should*** do the same thing, but under certain conditions, may not.

First of all note:

- that the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) entry description is misleading
- that [`wp-admin/includes/file.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L79) must be included in context else calling [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) will lead to calling an undefined function.

Regarding the codex entry,

> ### Description
>
> Get the absolute filesystem path to the root of the WordPress installation.
>
> ### Return Value
>
> Full filesystem path to the root of the WordPress installation. If you install wordpress in subfolder, it will show subfolder location
>
> ### Examples
>
> ```
> $path = get_home_path();
> print "Path: ".$path; // Return "Path: /var/www/htdocs/" or "Path: /var/www/htdocs/wordpress/" if it is subfolder
> ```

It states that the return value will return the path of the subfolder if you have installed WordPress in a sub-directory. This is in fact, incorrect.

[`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) will return the root directory of your WordPress installation, even if it's installed in a sub-directory. That is the purpose of the function.

Assume your WordPress installation is within a sub-directory called `/dev`,

- http://www.example.com/dev (`site_url`) (e.g. /var/www/htdocs/dev)
- http://www.example.com/    (`home_url`)

If you log a call to `ABSPATH`, then the result of which will be, `/var/www/htdocs/dev` which is **not** the root of your installation. The root of your installation is `/var/www/htdocs`.

`ABSPATH` is first defined in `wp-load.php` which will be located at `/var/www/htdocs/dev/wp-load.php` hence this is where `ABSPATH` will take its definition from.

If you inspect the [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) further you will note that if the `site_url` and `home_url` differ, then a sub-string is taken of the path governed by the position (first occurance) of the sub-directory found within the string.

```
function get_home_path() {
    $home    = set_url_scheme( get_option( 'home' ), 'http' );
    $siteurl = set_url_scheme( get_option( 'siteurl' ), 'http' );

    if ( ! empty( $home ) && 0 !== strcasecmp( $home, $siteurl ) ) {
        $wp_path_rel_to_home = str_ireplace( $home, '', $siteurl ); /* $siteurl - $home */
        $pos = strripos( str_replace( '\\', '/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ), trailingslashit( $wp_path_rel_to_home ) );
        $home_path = substr( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, $pos );
        $home_path = trailingslashit( $home_path );
    } else {
        $home_path = ABSPATH;
    }

    return str_replace( '\\', '/', $home_path );
}
```

Therefore, as a result of this, [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) and `ABSPATH` may return different results if you have WordPress installed in a sub-directory.

Secondly, calling [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) must be done in a context where the afortmentioned [`wp-admin/includes/file.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L79) has already been included.

As an example using [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) within the `admin_init` hook is fine where as using it within `init` is not.

Seeing as this file only gets included from within the admin (dashboard) context, if you absolutely need it outside of this context you will need to include the file yourself before calling the function,

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');`

Ironically (or not) which uses `ABSPATH` :D

Comment: Well explained, all though I think third party developers should neither use the constant nor the function. Because [WordPress can be located anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042543/), placing it outside the document root causes both the constant and the function to return e.g. `/var/apps/wordpress` instead of `/var/www/htdocs`. Rather use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, at least if you can assure that the document root wouldn't change.

Comment: @Fleuv Indeed this is a tricky one... even `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` has its issues... e.g.may not be set or set correctly and so on. There's other ways I can think of too to handle this... Each with their own caveats. Much fun :)

Comment: This solution was well explained and worked exactly as desired after WP was throwing the "not defined" error. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nicely explained by Adam but he didn't give **solution** to avoid using `ABSPATH`.

That is when we need to get wp-admin path and wp-admin/includes/file.php is also not included such as in init hook or execution on frontend.

We can avoid calling `ABSPATH` in `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');`
By copying `get_home_path()` definition into a file in your project and include that file if following condition meets like

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'get_home_path' ) ) {
      require_once MY_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/helpers/admin_functions.php';
    }
```

and inside your `MY_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/helpers/admin_functions.php'` copy the `get_home_path()` from 'wp-admin/includes/file.php'.

WP Update will also not cause the problem since this function depends only on php functions some minor include functions. **So we are avoiding ABSPATH when needed.**

Answer (score -1):

I am using **home_url()** for linking to the "Home" page of WP. Sometimes, **site_url()** may not be really your **home_url()**. You can define a spesific page as homepage in Wordpress.