# Get root folder without domain

Tags: urls

Sometimes when developing my theme my WordPress website will be on a obscure domain such as `http://localhost:8080/project/foo/bar`.

Is there a WordPress API function (or maybe just a PHP function) to get the root folder without the domain? So I am looking for a function that will give me `/project/foo/bar` without the `http://localhost:8080` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP stores this info in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Note that $_SERVER values can be spoofed, so is not always reliable.

Answer (score 1):

WP have `get_home_path` function which can provide you the o/p you're looking for but if its multinetwork site with subdirectory then it will provide you the subdir in the path. Also, you need to include the dependency file in order to access this function.

> require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
>
> $root_dir = get_home_path();

ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path

And if you need the root dir without any subdir in path you can use `ABSPATH` constant. 
http://example.com => 
`/var/www/example.com/htdocs/`

ref: [What's the difference between get_home_path() and ABSPATH?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188448/whats-the-difference-between-get-home-path-and-abspath)

Just for ref, WP has some other functions and constant which you can use as per your need.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories